# How to open localhost when connecting USB to a linux emb device

Tags: linux, web, embedded, usb, arm

I'm currently programming an arm embedded device. Currently I have installed thttpd and I have a web server running on the device. We have checked, using an ethernet connection, and everything runs fine. This web page controls systems running some sh script that execs c++ programs that communicates over pmpp with the final systems.

This device has an usb port that we plan to use to connect android / ios / bb devices(mobile phone or tablet) and open the same web page, for example, through 192.168.0.222.

Suppose I'm a worker and I have my company smartphone, I want to modify some values of the product so I just plug the usb, I access using safari/chrome or whatever navigator I decided to  use, change the values and go home to spend the rest of the afternoon with my family.

What we do not want to do it's to develop an application to retrieve the web page from the device to draw them if we have previously created it.

Comment: Please consider revising this question to a programming domain, it sounds like it might be just http://superuser.com/ related but the question meanders too far on non-relevant material.

Answer (score 1):

You have several fundamental architectural problems to solve here if you I understand the question correctly - which is that you want an ethernet connection over a direct USB connection with a mobile device, so that the mobile device can consume a web-service on your embedded system.

1) *USB roles*: One of the devices needs to have a USB Host Controller, and act as the host.  As it happens mobile phones support USB-OTG on their USB ports - and you'll be wanting to get them into host mode (appropriate cable for phones with micro-USB connectors,  [USB Camera Connection Kit](http://store.apple.com/uk/product/MC531ZM/A/apple-ipad-camera-connection-kit) for an iOS device).

2) *USB device role*: Your embedded device will need to implement an appropriate end-point for the host to communicate.  One option is the CDC Ethernet from the [Linux Gadget Framework](http://www.linux-usb.org/gadget/).  Provided your device has a functional USB Device stack and supports the gadget framework, this ought to be a case to changing your kernel config and recompiling.  Alternatively, you write a driver that spoofs an existing USB Ethernet dongle's API.

3) *USB Host drivers*: You will need a corresponding USB driver on host.  This is where it all starts to fall apart.  None of the phones are likely to ship with these.  On Android, you could in theory root the phone and then side-load additional drivers.  On iOS, the you need to join the [Made For iPnone](https://developer.apple.com/programs/mfi/) programme to even start to consider this.  Even the cost of getting on the scheme is covered by NDA, and it's only intended for volume OEMs.   I presume Blackberries are well locked down too.

Alternatively, an approach that is far more likely to work is to connect a USB Ethernet (cost: about $15) or Wifi dongle (Ethernet is far, far easier) to the USB Host port of your embedded device and bring that interface up on your office network.

In terms of implementing the embedded side of this, any webserver capable of CGI is a quick and dirty way of doing the job.